# color value of wpColorPicker

Tags: color-picker

I have following input field which is attached with color picker

```
<input type="text" class="color-field"   id="mn_fpl_colorbackconf" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea>
```

Also I have the following line in JS script

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.color-field', function() {
        jQuery('.color-field').wpColorPicker(); }
```

I have a small JS function

```
jQuery('#editfont_button').on('keyup', '#mn_fpl_colorbackconf', function() {
sel = jQuery('#graphics').find('#XYZ');
cls1 = sel.val();

sel2 = jQuery('#editfont_button').find('#mn_fpl_colorbackconf');
cls2 = sel2.val(); 

});
```

Here my question is how to get value of color in cls2 variable ?

Comment: I got the answer, it was in input value field only....